# MYSQL get multiple fields count using Group by multiple fields by date

Tags: mysql

I want count by using group two columns. I have data like this:

```
id     sectionid    date

1        1          2015-09-16
2        1          2015-09-16
3        2          2015-09-16
4        2          2015-09-16
5        3          2015-09-16
6        1          2015-09-17
7        2          2015-09-18
8        2          2015-09-18
```

Result will be:

```
 Date          section1count   section2count  section3count

 2015-09-16      2               2              1
 2015-09-17      1               0              0
 2015-09-18      0               2              0
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7674786/mysql-pivot-table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a combination of the `SUM()` function along with `GROUP BY` to get the result set you want:

```
SELECT date AS Date,
       SUM(CASE WHEN sectionid=1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS section1count,
       SUM(CASE WHEN sectionid=2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS section2count,
       SUM(CASE WHEN sectionid=3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS section3count
FROM table
GROUP BY date
```

[**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8887c/2)

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen can you explain how this query gets executed. Is the CASE WHEN in the sum filtering the rows to sum against?

Comment: Each `CASE WHEN` outputs a value into one of three count columns, depending on the value of the `sectionid` for that record.  The `GROUP BY` aggregates by the `date` and takes the `SUM` of the three counts.

Comment: So this is doable since the `SELECT` executes before `GROUP BY` so the `SUM` in the `section1count` will be `SUM(1)` for rows  with `sectionid=1` and `SUM(0)` for rows  with `sectionid!=1`. Then when the  `GROUP BY` aggregates it shall sum the rows with `SUM(1)`... Is this how it goes?. Am trying to analyze the execution process please correct me if am wrong..

Comment: The temporary table will contain three columns, one for each `sectionid` count.  During the `GROUP BY` operation, MySQL will `SUM` these columns, which as you pointed out will contain either zeroes or ones.  This gives you your result.

Comment: Thank you for your clarification :)

Answer (score 0):

her is my result. You can compare it to count each section

```
SELECT 
  SUM(IF( m.sectionid = 1 , 1,0)) section1count,
  SUM(IF( m.sectionid = 2 , 1,0)) section2count,
  SUM(IF( m.sectionid = 3 , 1,0)) section3count,
  m.date
   FROM myt m
   GROUP BY m.`date`;
```